# Infinite function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function that will call the function again at the end so it repeats itself indefinitely.

```
function foo2 () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#bloc2').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
        jQuery('#bloc2-vertical').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
        jQuery('#bloc2-horizontal').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
    }, 1000);
}
```

The function is already called in the footer but, for a specific page, #zonetexteposition height changes often automatically so I want the page to resize.

Comment: looks like you aren't calling the function again at the end, so why don't you try doing that first?

Comment: Infinite loops are almost never a good idea. Are you attempting to maintain an objects height at all times? I am not totally sure what you are attempting to do but maybe consider something event driven rather than infinite loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *repeatedly* call a function, you need [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), not `setTimeout`.

`setTimeout` invokes its callback *once*, after a delay. `setInterval` invokes its callback repeatedly until cancelled with `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it work with your code:

```
function foo2 () {
setTimeout(function(){
    foo2();
    jQuery('#bloc2').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
    jQuery('#bloc2-vertical').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
    jQuery('#bloc2-horizontal').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
    }, 1000);
}
foo2();
```

But it's better to use setInterval instead of setTimeout.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    jQuery('#bloc2').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
    jQuery('#bloc2-vertical').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
    jQuery('#bloc2-horizontal').height(jQuery('#zonetexteposition').height());
}, 1000);
```

Regarding not working in specific page, can you give more details/code?